# User Email Validation

Tags: php, html

Some I'm trying to make a web page that will prompt a user to enter his or her email and then determine if the email is a valid one or not. Here's my code so far (both the php files and html files are separate:

```
//code for emailvalidate.php
if (isset($_GET["email"])) {
    if (!filter_input(INPUT_GET, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        echo("Your email is valid");
    } else {
        echo("Your email is not valid. Please try again");
    }
}

//code for separate html file
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Email Checker</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="Form" action="emailvalidate.php" method="Get">
         Email: <input type='text' name='email' />
        <input type ='submit' value='Submit'/>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, whenever I try to run this code and put an email into the form and hit submit, it gives me the error message "Object Not Found!"
Could someone help me determine why I'm getting this error, and what I can do to correct it?
Thanks

Comment: So you copied the code from W3Schools and it failed? Color me shocked!

Comment: Just use `if (filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {`

Answer (score 0):

```
//code for emailvalidate.php
if (isset($_GET["email"])) {
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo("Your email is valid");
    } else {
        echo("Your email is not valid. Please try again");
    }
}
```

Also note that submitting forms with GET is insecure. Use POST instead